# Set the tab active dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two different components - Component1 and Component2 and a Service1.

When i click one image (One Product from List of Products) in the Component1(HomeComponent) using service (Service!), I'm setting the perticular productId in the service.

I want to use that perticular productId to make the tab (The Product List is Represented as Tabs) active in the Component2 (Products Component).

Can I get any help to accomplish this.

Im using Only Bootstrap Tabs.

HomeComponent Template:

```
 <div class="icon center-content" 
     (click)="getProductInfo(productsCategory.ProductCategoryID)">
      <img class="cat-image mb-4" [src]="productsCategory.ImagePath" alt="Place image title" *ngIf="!isImageLoading; else noImageFound">
        <ng-template #noImageFound>
          <img src="assets/img/fallbackImage.png" alt="Fallbackimage">
        </ng-template>
 </div>
```

HomeComponent:

```
getProductInfo(id){
console.log(id);
this.appService.getProductInfoHome(id);
this.router.navigateByUrl('home/products');
 }
```

ProductComponent Template:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
<li class="nav-item">
  <a id="tab-A" [routerLink]="['#pane-A']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" [class.active]="tab == 'tab-A'"     class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Product One</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a id="tab-B" [routerLink]="['#pane-B']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" [ngClass]="{'active': tab == 'tab-B'}"  class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Product Two</a>
</li>
```

ProductComponent:

```
//To get the tab details 
getTabDetails() {
      this.tab = this.appService.setActiveTab();
}


ngOnInit() {
//Stores the product ID from service
this.selectedProductID = this.appService.getProductID();
console.log(this.selectedProductID);

//Will call API and subscribes in the 
this.appService.getProductInfoHome(this.selectedProductID);
this.tab = this.appService.getActiveTab();
console.log(this.tab);
this.products = this.appService.firstProductData;
console.log(this.products);
}
```

App Service:

```
  //set Id
   setProductID(id) {
    this.selectedId = id;
  }

  //Get ID
  getProductID(){
     return this.selectedId;
   }

   //Get Product Info from home
  getProductInfoHome(id){
     this.getProductInfoById(id).subscribe(
     data=>{
       this.firstProductData = data;
       console.log(this.firstProductData);
       if(this.firstProductData){
       this.setActiveTab();
       console.log(this.selectTab);
      }
    },
     error=>{
        console.log(error);
    }
   )
  }

 //To set the tab active
  setActiveTab(): any {
   for (let cat of prodConfig.productCategory) {
     if (cat.ProductCategoryID === 
         this.firstProductData.ProductCategoryID) {
          this.selectTab = cat.ProductTabID;
       }
     }
   }

  //To get the active tab
   getActiveTab():any{
       if(this.selectTab)
       return this.selectTab;
    }


 //To get the product type and products byId
  getProductInfoById(productId) {
     const data = {
         productCategoryId: productId
      };
     const httpOptions = {
         headers: new HttpHeaders({
           'Content-Type':  'application/json'
        })
      };
      const reqData = JSON.stringify(data);


     return 
      this.http.post('/api/product/getinfobyid', reqData, 
     httpOptions).pipe(
       catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it 
         accordingly.
        console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
      } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.log(error.error);
       }
       return observableThrowError(error.error);
      }));
   }
```

Comment: add some code here what you tried till now and how your code looks like

Comment: Provide some code, please.

Comment: Have added the code, for what i tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Tabs is a javascript tab. It will not support back button in the browser. It will not route when you switch tabs. If you instead consider the tabs as an horizontal menu you could let every single tab represent a page. checkout:

https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-nested-routing-with-multiple-routeroutlet-using-loadchildren-having-own-router-modules-example-application/

section: Adding RouterOutlet directive at each level.

You could create a route: .../products/{id}. This would show a page with the product info. You could add it as a bookmark,send it as a link in a mail and so on. In your products page, route: ..../products. You get the products list and loop on you horizontal styled:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
    <li *ngFor="let product of products">
    <a routerLink="/products/{{product.Id}}">{{product.Name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the tab will route to the product/{id}. Using a styled the anchor link will make it possible for end user to rightclick and open in a new browser tab

Comment: As I'm using Boostrap accordian with each tab, so i have to display data of each product type and the list of products in that product type, that is why i require to show all the product types in a single component/module.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it in single component.

Comment: I think you need to send me an image of what you have. I don’t understand how you html should look like